# How to use android XML's with libgdx such as selector style, animations

Tags: android, xml, animation, libgdx, styles

I made a game previously with common Android libraries, and I made nice animations like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="1.3"
        android:toXScale="1.8"
        android:fromYScale="1.4"
        android:toYScale="0.9"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fillBefore="true"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:duration="800" />
    <set android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
        <scale
           android:fromXScale="1.8"
           android:toXScale="0.3"
           android:fromYScale="0.9"
           android:toYScale="0.2"
           android:pivotX="50%"
           android:pivotY="50%"
           android:startOffset="800"
           android:duration="600"
           android:fillBefore="false" />
        <rotate
           android:fromDegrees="0"
           android:toDegrees="-45"
           android:pivotX="50%" 
           android:pivotY="50%" 
           android:startOffset="800"
           android:duration="600" />
    </set>
    <scale
           android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
           android:fromXScale="0.3"
           android:toXScale="1.6"
           android:fromYScale="0.2"
           android:toYScale="1.4"
           android:pivotX="50%"
           android:pivotY="50%"
           android:startOffset="1400"
           android:duration="600"
           android:fillBefore="false"
           android:fillAfter="false" />
    <rotate
           android:fromDegrees="-45"
           android:toDegrees="45"
           android:pivotX="50%" 
           android:pivotY="50%" 
           android:startOffset="1400"
           android:duration="600" />
</set>
```

and I also made some custom buttons with styles:

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/light_blue"
                android:endColor="@color/dark_blue"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="@color/black" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
```

But I can't get them working on my LIBGDX project because it uses android libraries. I know there's a library called Tween but I'd rather make styles and animations like this.

```
Animation startAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.start_anim_two);
    startan.startAnimation(startAnimation);
```

Any idea of how to export them to LIBGDX project?

Comment: The Actions system in libgdx's Scene2D can do this kind of stuff, but you have to code it in Java. But if you want to write an XML interpreter that parses XML into Actions, I'm sure it would be a welcome addition to libgdx. :)

Comment: @Tenfour04 thank you for actions info, ill take a look